# SSRS - Why the sub-report is printed multiple times?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I'm new to SSRS and know little about groupings in SSRS.

I've an order confirmation report. The report has two groups (orderHead and orderLines). I've added a table row at the bottom of the report to contain a sub-report (that must run for some clients). This sub-report is not part of the grouping, but just sit at the bottom of the table.

[image: Sub-report image]

The problem I'm facing is that if the order has multiple lines, this sub-report is printed as many times as the order lines. How can I restrict it to print exactly once?
[image: Report Groups]

Comment: For testing, remove the subreport form last row and add some text. Check if it still repeating.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the subreport to print for each detail item, move it out of the detail group. I'd think you'd want it as a report footer, or possibly on the footer for group 1.

Comment: It is not part of any group. In fact the main group ends the row before it.

Comment: Is it possible that the subreport itself is causing 3 iterations (and it has nothing to do with the position of the subreport on the main report)? In other words, if you were to delete the grouping on the main report, does the subreport still show three times?

Comment: It doesn't iterate three times, but as many times as the order details/ lines. So if an order has 11 lines, it will print the sub-report 11 times.

Comment: Hrmmm. Sorry, doesn't look like this was very helpful. Want me to delete it?

Comment: It's ok, was just clarifying. It might actually be at the sub-report. I'll have to check it.

Comment: Does the sub get parameters from the detail? Would a workaround be to make a text box right under the main tablix containing the sub?

Comment: @JerryRitcey The sub-report does get the parameters from the detail. If I create a textbox under the main tablix, would I still be able to get the parameters from the tablix?

Comment: Do you need a sub for each detail? Or just the MAX or MIN record...?